Parent elements overflow act differently for different child elements?
I have problem with letting one child override parents overflow but not the other
#second-row {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    gap: 0px;
    height: 503px;
}

.inv {
    border: 1px solid rgb(37, 37, 37);
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 2px;
    background: rgba(65, 65, 65, 0.8);
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

.draggable-item {
    position: absolute;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    display: block;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

second-row is the parent element and inv is the slots that is the child that shouldt override the overflow and draggable-item is the items that should override the overflow. So i want draggable-item to override the second-rows overflow but not inv.
Thanks in advance :)

To get an answer on this question it would be a good idea to provide an example of, what the HTML looks like. Maybe an example of the HTML before and after something has been dropped.
